# Update grid view/db with combo box selected value :ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, combobox

i need to create a webpage containing a grid view with combo box. condition is:- the combo box value should be inserted on my SQL db and update the db/grid view when i click save button.[i added the image of proposed design of the page]any help with the code is so much appreciated! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GridView Markup**

Below I have a simple GridView ASP.Net GridView control populated from the Customers table of Northwind database. It displays 2 columns Contact Name and City of which city is editable via ASP.Net DropDownList control. The identifier column Customer Id is bind to the DataKeyNames property.

---

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" DataKeyNames = "CustomerId" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" OnRowEditing = "EditCustomer" OnRowDataBound = "RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating = "UpdateCustomer" OnRowCancelingEdit = "CancelEdit">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField = "ContactName" HeaderText = "Contact Name" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "City">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City")%>' Visible = "false"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID = "ddlCities" runat = "server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Binding the GridView**

---

Below is the code to Bind the GridView control with data.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindData();
    }
}

private void BindData()
{
    string query = "SELECT top 10 * FROM Customers";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    gvCustomers.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
    gvCustomers.DataBind();
}

private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Editing the GridView Row

---

The below events handle the GridView Row Edit and Cancel Edit Events
C#

```
protected void EditCustomer(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvCustomers.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();
}

protected void CancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvCustomers.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}
```

---

---